# sending and receive data from client using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, wifi, tcpclient

I am using 
[RS485 to wifi router](http://en.usr.cn/Wifi-Serial-Server/RS485-to-WIFI-802.11-B-G-N-Converter.html)

above model for Rs485 communication.

Intailly  I tried simple code with arduino. WIth sending serial data over client for every 2S.

```
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop()
{
 Serial.println("SMCB1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"); 
  delay(2000);
}
```

I used below python code, to receive data from client 1 and client 2

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.3'
TCTCP_IP1='192.168.1.2'
TCP_PORT = 8899
BUFFER_SIZE = 100
BUFFER_SIZE1=100
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s1.connect((TCTCP_IP1, TCP_PORT))

s.send(MESSAGE)
s1.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
data1= s1.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

s.close()
s1.close()
print "received data:", data
print "received data:", data1
```

Now i have uploaded the Modbus RTU code , where i am sending request and trying to get response. Request need to send in Hex format. I tried with wired communication seems working fine.
I have shared request format below. But i could able to read any thing process will under progress to read

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.3'
TCTCP_IP1='192.168.1.2'
TCP_PORT = 8899
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
BUFFER_SIZE1=1000

#MESSAGE = "01 03 00 00 00 1d 85 c3"
#MESSAGE1 = "02 03 00 00 00 1d 85 fo"

MESSAGE = "01030000001d85c3"
MESSAGE1 = "02030000001d85fo"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print "Before connect"

s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s1.connect((TCTCP_IP1, TCP_PORT))

print "After connect"
print MESSAGE
print MESSAGE1

print "request before sending"
s.send(MESSAGE1)
s1.send(MESSAGE)
print "request after  sending"
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
data1= s1.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

s.close()
s1.close()
print "received data:", data
print "received data:", data1
```

Now problem I am facing i am trying to send request but i could not able to get reply. With wired communication i can able to get data.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified code i am getting response. Need to help to convert data into decimal format. to understna received data correct or not. I need to convert whole data into decimal format. Let me know how can achieve this

```
import socket
TCP_IP = '192.168.1.3'
TCP_PORT = 8899
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.send('01030000001d85c3'.decode('hex'))

Decode_hex='01030000001d85c3'.decode('hex')
print Decode_hex
print "decode hex:",Decode_hex


data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()

print "data recieved :", data
d=data.encode('hex').upper()
print 'Hexa decimal value deceived:',repr(d)

mod_hex=data.encode('hex').upper()
print 'Hexa decimal value Modified:',repr(mod_hex)

#print 'received',d
decimal=int(d,20)
print "decimal converted value:",decimal
```

Here is out put file attached

> decode hex:  data recieved : : Hexa decimal value deceived:
>   '01033A0000000D00120041003400410056004B000000000000000000DF000000E1000000E700F800E600EC0000000000000000001F00010001000100DC496E'
>   Hexa decimal value Modified:
>   '01033A0000000D00120041003400410056004B000000000000000000DF000000E1000000E700F800E600EC0000000000000000001F00010001000100DC496E'
>   decimal converted value:
>   214364598880234057828928146607817359105482384449559342919180352622648369076567392756173653847449417881349290133492250705920000000000003670016655364096025643555734